# Use case for pushing remote branches to another remote repo in git

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

In git, we can push a remote branch to another remote like this:

```
> git clone git@foo1.com:a/a
> cd a
> git remote add other git@foo2.com:b/b
> git fetch --all
# ...
> git push origin other/master
Counting objects: 107, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (66/66), done.
Writing objects: 100% (107/107), 2.11 MiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 107 (delta 52), reused 87 (delta 33)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (52/52), completed with 8 local objects.
To foo1.com:a/a
 * [new branch]        other/master -> other/master
```

So on "@foo1.com:a/a", we can see it got the remote of "foo2.com:b/b", by using the `git branch -va` command:

```
* master                  7c6051f foo
  remotes/other/master    38a5a1b bar
```

If we just use `git branch -v` this remote branch wouldn't appear.

However I can't think how this is useful. There is no way for my local to interact with this on `foo1.com:a/a` right? Could someone gives a potential use case for this?

Also could this somehow be disabled with some git configuration?

Answer (score 0):

> So on "@foo1.com:a/a", we can see it got the remote of "foo2.com:b/b", by using the `git branch -va` command:

No you don't: `git branch -av` is purely a *local* command, which lists local branches done in your local repo.
That branch `remotes/other/master` is not present on your remote repo `foo1.com:a/a`. Only `master` is.

`remotes/other/master` is a local "remote tracking branch" meant for your local repo to remember what was pushed to or pull from the remote repo "`other`" for the branch "`master`".

```
git push origin other/master
```

That would indeed create another branch named `other/master` to the remote repo `origin` (`foo1.com`)

But you usually don't need that: you do a local merge between the local remote tracking branch `other/master` and your own master, then push `master` itself with a simple `git push`.

Comment: I ran `git branch -va` on the  "@foo1.com:a/a" remote server's repository, and it's indeed there, with the correct SHA for b/b's master

Comment: Thanks, so I guess you also think this has no use case and could be banned with no sideeffects?

Comment: @lulalala yes, that would not be a usual use case, but it cannot be banned easily: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30471886/6309