# How to mirror a devops repository to GitHub, but exclude 1 folder

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops, gitignore

I have a private Microsoft Azure-Devops/TFS Pipeline. This pipeline builds my code and also mirrors it's content to a public github repository.

Now I'd like the pipeline to *not* mirror some folders, since I want to keep these folders private. I can't just change the git-ignore files and I fail to build a script that deletes the folder before commiting it to github.

So how do I handle this type of problem? Is there any way to pull-push a repository, excluding one specific folder, without the gitignore?

```
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: 'git pull https://$(githubpersonaltoken)@github.com/MyRepo/MyFile.git master'

- task: DeleteFiles@1
  displayName: 'Delete folder'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder:
    Contents: '.deletedFolderName*'
    RemoveSourceFolder: true


- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: 'git push https://$(githubpersonaltoken)@github.com/MyRepo/MyFile.git head:master'
```

Expected result: Changes in "deletedFolderName" would not be mirrored by the push task.
Result: Everything is pushed.

Comment: Where are you committing the changes? You `pull`, delete something, then `push` the repo without having committed anything. However, there's something suspect here: What is this "private" content that you don't want to mirror? If it's secrets, then you are solving the wrong problem. The problem to solve is that you are **storing secrets in source control**, which is a terrible practice.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new branch that includes the folder, remove/purge everything else, then **don't ever push this branch**.  There are various methods to prevent accidental pushing of branches - [here's one specific to GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51565719/423125)

```sh
#create new branch
git checkout -b SecretSauce

#optional - track only "SecretFolder", ignore everything else via .gitignore
echo '/*' > .gitignore
echo '!.git*' >> .gitignore
echo '!/Secret Folder' >> .gitignore

#apply standard git ignore behavior only to current index, not working directory (--cached)
#if this command returns nothing, ensure /.git/info/exclude AND/OR .gitignore exist
git ls-files -z --ignored --exclude-standard | xargs -0 git rm --cached
git add *
git commit -m "ignored everything but SecretFolder"
```

If the folder in question **is now/ever was** contained in the repository, and that repo was subsequently pushed to GitHub, the folder is **now** accessible via GitHub revision history, in whatever state it was at the time it was included/pushed.  You can see this for yourself - from the GitHub repo, click 'commits', and then click the `< >` next to a commit that might've included your folder.  This allows you to browse the repository as it appeared for that commit. If this is a problem, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57454176/423125).

For each branch, will need to `git checkout branch` and then modify the `/.git/info/exclude` file to match the .gitignore file as it appears in the respective branch, run the `git filter-branch` command **without** the `--all` switch, and then revert `/.git/info/exclude` afterward, to ensure this procedure properly applies the desired ignorations (different per-branch)